# Prove that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} t^p\ d\mu \lt \infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-integral, monotone-functions

> Let $f : [0,1] \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ be a monotonically increasing function (not necessarily continuous) with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1.$ Suppose $\mu$ denotes the Borel measure on $[0,1]$ such that $\mu \left (\left (a,b \right ] \right )$ is the cardinality of the set $\displaystyle \left \{x \in [0,1]\ \bigg |\ a \lt \lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \left [f(x+h) - f(x) \right ] \leq b \right \}$ for all $0 \leq a \lt b \leq 1.$ Prove that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} t^p\ d\mu \lt \infty$ for $p > 1.$

How do I solve this question? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $f$ has countably many right discontinuities at $x_n$, and their 'sizes' $s_n = f(x_n+) - f(x_n)$ is a countable sequence such that $\sum_n s_n \le 1$.

Then $\mu((a,b])$ is the cardinality of those $n$ such that $s_n \in (a,b]$.  That is, $$ \int h \, d\mu = \sum_n h(s_n) .$$

Comment: Is it obvious that $s_n$ is countable ? I was thinking as a strategy to verify this to suppose that it is not countable and use this to find a subsequence such that $s_k  \rightarrow a$, with $a>0$. Than we would have a contradiction because the discontinuities would add to a number larger than 1. Would this be correct ? Is there a simpler reason ?

Comment: It is a well known result that the discontinuities of a monotone function are countable.  Let $E_\epsilon$ be the set of discontinuities whose sizes are larger than $\epsilon$.  Then the cardinality of $E_\epsilon$ is less than $1/\epsilon$.  And the set of discontinuities is $\bigcup_k E_{1/k}$.

Comment: @Thomas Notice that $\mu((1/n,1])\} \le n$ to prove the countability of the *jumps*.

Comment: Great considering the discontinuities in $E_{1/n}$ was indeed what I had in mind in my comment to find that subsequence, so I guess qualitatively the reasonings are all the same. ( In my case was proceeding by contradiction. If the set was not countable one of the $E_{1/n}$ should be infinite, from which we can derive that subsequence and the contradiction. ) Thanks to both.

Comment: How do you write $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} h\ d\mu = \displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} h \left ( s_n \right )$?

Comment: Show that it is true for simple functions, which boils down to showing it is true for the indicator function of a measurable set, which boils down to showing it is true for the indicator function of $(a,b]$.

Comment: I have proved it for non-negative simple measurable functions. Now for any non-negative measurable function $f$ there exists a sequence of non-negative simple measurable functions $\{f_m\}_{m \geq 1}$ increases to $f.$ Then by MCT we have $$\int_{0}^{1} f(t)\ dt = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_m(t)\ dt.$$ Now since $f_m$'s are non-negative simple measurable function we have $$\int_{0}^{1} f_m (t)\ dt = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} f_m (s_n).$$

Comment: So what we have is that $$\int_{0}^{1} f(t)\ dt = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} f_m (s_n).$$ Can we interchange the limit and the summation to write $$\int_{0}^{1} f(t)\ dt = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} f(s_n)\ ?$$ Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, because MCT also applies to sums (which are a special case of integrals).

Comment: But MCT for sums requires the idea that integral of a function with respect to counting measure is precisely an infinite sum which I'm trying to prove. So can I use this result?

Comment: Yes.  Why do you say not?